# QML: Anchor to the actual displayed position of an Image (resized with fillMode)

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I want to add a `Text` at the bottom of an `Image`.

I do not know the size of the image or the size of its parent, but the image needs to cover the whole space of its parent (either the whole width or the whole height).

My problem is: since I use `anchors.fill: parent` on the `Image,` the `Text` is positionned at the bottom of the parent component. How can I position it at the bottom of the image without knowing its actual position?

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 500

    Image {
        source: "http://images.wikia.com/pt.starwars/images/c/c4/Yoda2.jpg"
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        anchors.fill: parent // to cover the whole available space

        Text {
            anchors {
                horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                bottom: parent.bottom
            }
            text: "Judge me by my size, do you?"
        }
    }
}
```

What I have:

[image: Bad position of the text]

What I want:

[image: Good position - vertical mode]
[image: Good position - horizontal mode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused because one thing is the size of the item Image and the other is the size of the scaled image since you have enabled `anchors.fill: parent` and the `fillMode : Image.PreserveAspectFit`, with the first one you are telling it to occupy all the screen and with the second that is scaled in the best way so that the complete image is observed.

The Item Image has the property [`paintedHeight`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#paintedHeight-prop) that indicates the height of the scaled image so if we use it next to the height of the item Image with the height of the text we obtain the desired position:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 500

    Image {
        source: "http://images.wikia.com/pt.starwars/images/c/c4/Yoda2.jpg"
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        anchors.fill: parent // to cover the whole available space
        Text {
            anchors {
                horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            }
            y: (parent.height + parent.paintedHeight)/2 - height
            text: "Judge me by my size, do you?"
        }
    }
}
```